# Should i close each substreams of filestream or closing filestream will be enought?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

I readed a lot of topics about C# streams, but did not find my situation.
For learing purpose i did list-file json-bd like:

```
public sealed class JSONBD<T> : IDisposable {
    private FileStream fileStream;
    private TextWriter textWriter; // textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream)
    private TextReader textReader; // textReader = new StreamReader(fileStream)
    public List<T> Bd { get; set; } // null is not awailable here
    public string FilePath { get; }
    public void Open();
    public void Commit();
    public void Close();
}
```

I tryed to use System.IO streams because they are garantee the only user of it file will be a current instance.
Much time in living time object i need to commit, so i cant using `using` construction because `StreamWriter` instance closes my `FileStream` when commiting like `StreamReader` after deserealization the file. Well, i need to close both of them?

So i decided to use one `FileStream`, `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` objects at the same time.
The problem is: is it correct to do that way, having 2 streams from `FileStream`?
The second problem is: how should i close these streams? Will be `FileStream.Close()` enough or not? At the topics i didnt find any exact solution about that instead closing lower stream. But i have 2 lower streams actually! Well, should i close both of them? But one of them already closes `FileStream`.

I am really sorry for english mistakes i did. Im still in progress.

Comment: I think you want one filestream per file you're reading or writing. If you want to create a collection of filestreams, you can, but you can't use one filestream for two files at the same time. You definitely want to close your filestream when you are done writing to it.

Comment: Vic F, thanks for answering!
I use only single file, so there is only one `FileStream` per file. But 2 streams for `FileStream`. Sorry for that misunderstanding.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to use the same FileStream with StreamReader & StreamWriter at the same time. Because StreamReader _always_ buffers, so once you read from the reader, then write and flush to the writer, the reader's buffer will _not_ be reset, and thus reading once more might still get somewhat unexpected old and now overwritten characters. It's of course all very circumstantial (not least dependent on the buffer size and text encoding used by the StreamReader and where the reads and writes happen in which order), but one thing it is for sure: that approach is not very robust. ;-)

Comment: MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, thanks for answer.
Okay, i will edit that, but how i be sure that file is busy when instanse.IsOpen?
I'm also wondering how Read Write access should be used